# Generate a URL for a specific route pattern in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "JobsIndex",
    url: "Jobs/{filter}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Jobs", action = "Index", filter = "Recent" }
);
```

How do I create an url to it? Something like:

`http://localhost/Jobs/Active`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrei was first with the right answer here. I just wanted to point out that you can also use the route name you gave via `Url.RouteUrl`:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("JobsIndex", new { filter = "Active" })
```

Comment: Although your answer came later I like this solution better, so I'll give you best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Inside controller:

```
string url = Url.Action("Index", "Jobs", new {filter = "Active"});
```

On a view:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Jobs", new { filter = "Active" })
```

Comment: I tried this: `<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Jobs", new { filter = "Recent" })">Recent Jobs</a></li>` and the result was `http://localhost/Jobs`

Comment: @elite5472, most likely you have other routes that are registered  before JobIndex and thus are shadowing it. Can you post the whole routing registration?

Comment: Okay, now I know why it doesn't work. '/Recent' is the default... Active worked just fine.

Comment: This answer is correct. Though I marked Chris's as best since I liked his solution better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which will create the URL for you.

`var url = Url.Action("Jobs", "Index", new { filter = "Active" });`

You can also use this in your JavaScript files which comes in useful when attempting to get the URL in the View. You can do this with `Razor`

```
@Url.Action("Jobs", "Index", new { filter = "Active" });
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP wants the "Active" filter passed. This doesn't do that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - added the `Active` filter in.